# When using the podman container to execute the command, the file cannot be created

Tags: docker, podman

I am using the above command to try to run a python script and redirect the result into a file.

```
podman run -it -v$(pwd):/mnt --rm python3:v1  /bin/bash -c "cd /mnt; sudo python3 Python/get_data.py y output/spec2k17 > single.csv"
```

But got the following error.

```
/bin/bash: single.csv: Permission denied
```

When I directly enter the container to execute, even if sudo is added, the file cannot be created.

```
> $ podman run -it -v$(pwd):/mnt --rm python3:v1  /bin/bash
> docker@ab368cd9d3a2:~/data$ cd /mnt/ 
> docker@ab368cd9d3a2:/mnt$ sudo python3 Python/get_data.py y output/spec2k17 > single.csv 
> bash: single.csv: Permission denied
```

How should I solve this problem? Thank you so much! ! !

Comment: On what distribution or OS are you running podman?